# Jquery Autocomplete textbox using WCF Service in Visual Webpart Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, sharepoint, web-parts

How to make autocomplete textbox using jquery calling wcf services in visual webpart in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Another option depending on your requirements (you don't give much to go on) is to either use or customize SPAutocomplete in [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com). The SPAutocomplete function is written in script so it functions fully client side, using the Lists Web Service to grab its source values from a list you specify.

Comment: Thanks All, I am required to do textbox autocomplete using Jquery and WCF in sharepoint fetching values from sql server.